# Tkinter: Win check in scalable tic tac toe not working

Tags: python, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a scalable tic tac toe game in Tkinter (meaning the board size can be 2x2 up to whatever fits the screen). I'm using `cget("image")` to find what mark a button has. For some reason, the win check displays very random things. I've tried a lot of semi-random things to fix it, but had no success in fixing it. Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class XOGame:
    def main_game(self):
        self.__game_window = Tk()
        self.__grid_size = 3 # User inputted in a different part of the code
        self.__game_window.title("Tic Tac Toe (" + str(self.__grid_size) + "x"
                                     + str(self.__grid_size) + ")")

        # this is user inputted in a different part of the program.
        self.__players = ["p1", "p2"]
        self.__player1 = self.__players[0]
        self.__player2 = self.__players[1]

        self.build_board(self.__game_window)

        self.__game_window.mainloop()


    def build_board(self, window):
        self.__size = self.__grid_size ** 2
        self.__turn_nr = 1
        self.__win = False

        self.__empty_square = PhotoImage(master=window,
                                         file="rsz_empty.gif")
        self.__x = PhotoImage(master=window,
                              file="rsz_cross.gif")
        self.__o = PhotoImage(master=window,
                              file="rsz_nought.gif")

        self.__squares = [None] * self.__size
        self.create_win_check_lists()

        # Building the buttons and gridding them
        for i in range(self.__size):
            self.__squares[i] = (Button(window, image=self.__empty_square))
        row = 0
        column = 0
        number = 1
        for j in self.__squares:

            j.grid(row=row, column=column)
            j.config(command=lambda index=self.__squares.index(j):
                     self.change_mark(index))
            column += 1
            if number % 3 == 0:
                row += 1
                column = 0
            number += 1

# This is the part where the picture changing happens.
    def change_mark(self, i):
        """
            Function changes mark of empty button to either X or O depending on the
            player in turn. It also checks if the change in mark results in a win.
            :param i: The button number, whose mark is being changed
            :return: None
        """
        if self.__turn_nr % 2 == 1:
            self.__player_in_turn = self.__player1

        else:
            self.__player_in_turn = self.__player2

        if self.__player_in_turn == self.__player1:
            self.__mark = self.__x
        else:
            self.__mark = self.__o

        self.__squares[i].configure(image=self.__mark, state=DISABLED)

        self.__turn_nr += 1

        self.check_win(i)

        if self.__win is True:
            print("this is thought to be a win")
        else:
            print("the game thinks this is not a win")

        # Checking if the game tied.
        if self.__turn_nr == self.__size + 1 and not self.__win:
            print("the game thinks it tied.")

    def check_win(self, i):
        """
        Checks if mark placement leads to a win.
        :param i: i is the button location.
        :return: None
        """

                # checks row
        if self.__win == False:
            for row in self.__rows:
                if i + 1 in row:
                    self.__win = self.checksameimage(row)
                    if self.__win == True:
                        break

        # checks column
        if self.__win == False:
            for column in self.__columns:
                if i + 1 in column:
                    self.__win = self.checksameimage(column)
                    if self.__win == True:
                        break

        # if i is in a diagonal, checks one/both diagonals
        if self.__win == False:
            for diag in self.__diagonals:
                if i + 1 in diag:
                    self.__win = self.checksameimage(diag)
                    if self.__win == True:
                        break

        return self.__win

    # checking if all the images are same
    # This is likely where the issue is. Either this part or checkEqual.
    def checksameimage(self, lst):
        images = []
        for nr in lst:
            try:
                images.append(self.__squares[nr].cget("image"))
            except IndexError:
                pass

        return self.checkEqual(images)

    def checkEqual(self, lst):
        """
        Function checks if all elements in a list are equal. Used for checking
        if the dice throws are the same.
        :param lst: The list the check is performed on
        :return: True/False, True if all elements are equal.
        """
        if all(x == lst[0] for x in lst):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def create_win_check_lists(self):
        """
        Creates lists whose elements are lists of the locations of each spot
        of the game board that belongs to a row/column/diagonal
        :return:
        """

        self.__rows = [[] for _ in range(self.__grid_size)]

        for i in range(self.__grid_size):
            self.__rows[i].append(i + 1)
            for k in range(1, self.__grid_size):
                self.__rows[i].append(i + 1 + self.__grid_size * k)

        self.__columns = [[] for _ in range(self.__grid_size)]

        for i in range(self.__grid_size):
            for j in range(1, self.__grid_size + 1):
                self.__columns[i].append(i * self.__grid_size + j)

        self.getDiagonals(self.__columns)

    def getDiagonals(self, lst):

        self.__diagonals = [[], []]
        self.__diagonals[0] = [lst[i][i] for i in range(len(lst))]
        self.__diagonals[1] = [lst[i][len(lst) - i - 1] for i in
                               range(len(lst))]

    def start(self):
        # Function starts the first window of the game.
        self.main_game()


def main():
    ui = XOGame()
    ui.start()


main()
```

The images used in the code are 125x125. Here is a link that works for 24h: https://picresize.com/b5df006025f0d8

Comment: `if self.__win == True:   break` doesn't stop it from overriding `self.__win` to false in the next loop. also the code to generate the winning rows and columns is sufficiently unreadable I suspect that might be wrong.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Sorry, fixed the self.__win overriding issue. The generating of rows, columns and diagonals works perfectly, I've tested it extensively. The issue I believe is specifically with the function checksameimage or checkEqual.

Comment: you say "believe" but surely a few print statements would quickly demonstate that your `checksameimage` is ending up with a list with 2-3 elements of `"pyimage1"` which corresponds to the blank space image.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes, I know that, I've seen it in the debugger. As a beginner coder, it's a bit hard for me to see the information in the buttons, which leaves me feeling a bit confused at times. The issue is that even though checksameimage has instances of pyimage1, the program thinks the game was won. I don't really understand why, and since this is the first time I'm doing a larger program it's a bit difficult to wrap my head around it all to be honest. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you for taking time out of your day this far as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is unquestionably with indices. We can see what index each square corresponds to by changing the image to be text corresponding to the index:

Try changing this loop in `build_board`:

```
    for i in range(self.__size):
        self.__squares[i] = (Button(window, image=self.__empty_square))
```

To instead show the index it corresponds to:

```
    for i in range(self.__size):
        self.__squares[i] = (Button(window, text=str(i)))
```

Then print out `lst` passed to `checksameimage` and you will see that the indices you are checking are all one higher than you intended.